# PhoneGap GCM-|Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I use the following  plugin: marknutter/GCM-Cordova from git hub.

I installed this plugin on eclipse and ran it on an android device. 
I manage to register the device for GCM messages + receive messages.

When The device receives a message from Google Cloud, it calls the onMessage event  handler, line 55, in this file: 
https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova/blob/master/src/com/cordova2/gcm/GCMIntentService.java

The event handler reaches line 77 to run this command: GCMPlugin.sendJavascript( json );
this commands supposed to send the data received to the webView of the app. 
However the static class' GCMPlugin members, are not initialized at all so, when the call to GCMPlugin.sendJavascript( json ) all the members of GCMPlugin  members are null. As a result an exception occurs and the message can't be delivered to the webView.

Anyone has an idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

I would not waste any time trying to run some obscure plug-ins, when there is officially supported PhoneGap plugin for push notifications: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin. I'm using it in a couple of my apps already and it works wonders. Updates to it are pushed every couple of months.

Comment: Officially supported PhoneGap plugin? sounds promissing... i'll try it.

Comment: Does this plugin supports calling js functions when receiving a notification, that is, wake the application, handle the onMessage event in native code with the message data, and then calling a js function from the native code?

Comment: This "obscure plug-in" you are refering to is the foundation of the Android part of the PushPlugin. Please inform yourself before bashing the unknown. See https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin#acknowledgments

Comment: no harm/insult was intended, I just suggested using the more widespread plug-in (supported by PG) which I have experience with and know works.

Comment: @Omeriko did you find a solution to this. I am using the GCM plugin for exactly what you describe: receiving notifications even when the application is not running, but it is not compatible with later versions of Cordova. Did you try the phonegap plugin? Does it receive notifications when app is not running? Just before I start to re-write whole chunks of my app

Comment: Having a quick read it looks like it does: ...Your app may receive a notification while it is active (INLINE). If you background the app by hitting the Home button on your device, you may later receive a status bar notification. Selecting that notification from the status will bring your app to the front and allow you to process the notification. Finally, should you completely exit the app by hitting the back button from the home page, you may still receive a notification. Touching that notification ... will relaunch your app and allow you to process the notification.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I'm working on this plugin to support the latest Cordova and using the latest GCM from Google which will allow you to send push notifications to Android and iOS devices: https://github.com/gonzaloaune/GCMPushPlugin

Comment: I tried your plugin, but unfortunately it doesn't work , Do you have any working sample code ? 

ever time I have errors like  
"Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.0.1" . NOTE: I use "grunt-cordovacli" to build my android application. and I reviewed the SDK , nothing missing.
It would help alot if you have working phonegap sample .